# Cast some columns and select all columns without explicitly writing column names

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I want to cast some columns and then select all others

```
id, name, property, description = column("id"), column("name"), column("property"), column("description")

select([cast(id, String).label('id'), cast(property, String).label('property'), name, description]).select_from(events_table)
```

Is there any way to cast some columns and select all with out mentioning all column names

I tried

```
select([cast(id, String).label('id'), cast(property, String).label('property')], '*').select_from(events_table)

py_.transform(return_obj, lambda acc, element: acc.append(dict(element)), [])
```

But I get two extra columns (total 7 columns) which are cast and I can't convert them to dictionary which throws key error.

**I'm using FASTAPI, sqlalchemy and databases(async)**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you can do

```
select_columns = []
for field in events_table.keys()
    select_columns.append(getattr(events_table.c, field))

select(select_columns).select_from(events_table)
```

to select all fields from that table. You can also keep a list of fields you want to actually select instead of events_table.keys(), like

```
select_these = ["id", "name", "property", "description"]
select_columns = []
for field in select_these
    select_columns.append(getattr(events_table.c, field))

select(select_columns).select_from(events_table)
```

Comment: thanks, I got a workaround for that, events_table is a sqlalchemy.Table so I had to do events_table.columns.keys()                                             `column_names = py_.transform(list(events_table.columns.keys()),
                                 lambda acc, value: acc.append(column(value)) if value not in ['id', 
                                 'property'] else acc.append(cast(column(f'{value}'), 
                                  String).label(f'{value}')), [])`          and then run the query           `query = select(column_names).select_from(main.app.events_table)`